# Java sql execute with more variable

Tags: java, sql, label

I have a frame with 50 label, i can select them, for example i select A1,A2,A3,A4 the program save these in string (String=A1;A2;A3;A4) and i want to call in this query

```
    try{

   String sql= "UPDATE Teremszekek SET Állapot='Foglalt' where Terem='1' and Szék='A1' and DKód='1' ";  

         PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          pst.execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Állapot=condition(available,unavailable)  Terem=room(index of room)  Szék=chair DKód=Date code

**How can i write that if i choose, A1,A2,A3,A4 etc label then it paste to query**

//i select them at the same time

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you please clarify what you want to do?

Comment: So, i choose 5 label of 50 label, for example A1,A2,A3,A4,G6 i want to update my database like this ` String sql= "UPDATE Teremszekek SET Állapot='Foglalt' where Terem='1' and Szék='A1' and DKód='1' ";`
` String sql= "UPDATE Teremszekek SET Állapot='Foglalt' where Terem='1' and Szék='A2' and DKód='1' ";`
etc, and the label value is saved in a String, but these values always changes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question in the right way, this should be your solution:

```
String sql= "UPDATE Teremszekek SET Állapot='Foglalt' where Terem='1' and Szék=? and DKód='1' ";  

pst.setString(1, yourValue);
```

Comment: thx this is useful, and what if my value is `String= "A1,A2,G3"` and i have to set in `Szék=?` like this `Szék='A1'` `Szék='A2'`

Comment: @Sanyaetrone: if you have more than one value you have to use `Szék in ? ` with a list of Strings: `stmt.setParameterList(1,Arrays.asList(string));`

Comment: i dont know why dowvoted somebody this answer, thx i will try this :) and not pst? or simple statement?

Comment: Does this work? I'm no SQL expert but I think for a parameter list you need to use `IN (A, B, C)` rather than just `=`. (Not the downvoter)

Comment: @BoristheSpider JDBC schold convert it in this style.